# Resources that describe schemes for nondimensionalization of ODEs and PDEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

I am able to find plenty of notes that give examples of how a few particular examples may be non-dimensionalized, but I am wondering if there is something more general worth studying?

A benefit of a more general approach, rather than an example based approach would be that one could possibly develop a scheme which may be used to non-dimensionalize any problem.

Also, it might be easier to learn, since perhaps one could grasp the pattern from the general case easier than a bunch of specific problems they have no interest in.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general method of non-dimensionalization is given by the [Buckingham Pi Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem)

I learned it from [Introduction to Symmetry Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521771838), but amazingly enough there is an [entire book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642195644) on the subject.